# There exist nonempty connected subset $X$ of $\mathbb{R^n}$ such that $X$ has more than two elements and has only rational numbers in it.

Tags: real-analysis

There exist nonempty connected subset $X$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $X$ has more than two
elements and has only rational numbers in it.

I think the statement is not correct because after taking irrational numbers from a subset of $\mathbb{R}$,it becomes a set which is not connected any more.
Am I right or wrong? somebody please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right. But in order to prove that you need to show that if $X\subseteq\Bbb Q$ contains two distinct $x<y$ then we can write $X$ as the union of two disjoint relatively open sets. That is to say, there are two open sets in $\Bbb R$, $U$ and $V$ which are non-empty, disjoint and $X=(X\cap U)\cup(X\cap V)$.

**HINT:** Pick an irrational number $x<r<y$ and use it to define open sets for the partition above.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is a nonempty connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with only rational numbers in it, $X$ has only one element.

To see this, note at least one point $a$ of $X$ is an isolated point (there is some open ball with only $a$ in it). Suppose otherwise, ie. all points of $X$ are cluster points, ie $X$ is perfect. Since $X$ is a nonempty, complete, perfect space (being a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which is complete), we have $X$ is uncountable which is a contradiction since $X \subset \mathbb{Q}$ which is countable.

So $X$ has some isolated point, say $a \in X$. Then $X=\{a\} \sqcup (X/\{a\})$ and since $\{a\}$ is clopen, $X/\{a\}=\emptyset$, ie. $X$ has only point.